# Is there a way to get type-metadata from an object during debugging

Tags: c#, debugging

The codebase I'm working on now has a lot of ye olde `ArrayLists` and `Hashtables`. Is it possible to find out what type one of the member items is from the debugger?

Comment: some code examples will be greatly appreciated. With screenshots you'll be granted extra points...

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.object.gettype.aspx

Comment: Use the immediate window or a add a watch. eg: `list[0].GetType()`

Comment: @sircodesalot: Added as answer then :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the immediate window or a add a watch. eg:

`list[0].GetType()`